# Laravel User Login Fail

Tags: laravel

i am going to make a login form with validation.if the username and password correct user shall be able to login other wise login failed.but i gave the correct username and password also login fail. i don't know why what i tried so far i attached below. password set as encrypted

**LoginController**

```
  public function check(Request $request)
    {  
       $credentials = [
                'email' => $request['email'],
               'password' =>  $request['password'],
            ];
         //   dd($credentials);
        $input['password'] = bcrypt($input['password']);

    
        if (Auth::attempt($request->only($credentials))) 
        {
            echo "Sucess";
        }
        echo "fail";

    }
```

**Login view**

```
@extends('layout')
@section('content')
  

    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">Contact Form</div>
        <div class="card-body"> 
        
            <form action= "{{ route('check') }}" method="post">
             {!! csrf_field() !!}   

            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class ="form-control"> </br>


            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class ="form-control"> </br>


            <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-success"> 


            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

@stop
```

Comment: line ``$input['password'] = bcrypt($input['password']);`` doesn't make sense.

Comment: change ``'password' =>  $request['password'],`` to ``'password' =>  bcrypt ($request['password']),`` and it should work !!

Comment: you're attempting auth validation on the ``$credentials`` variable which contains raw password which is why authentication is getting failed!

Comment: 'password' =>  bcrypt($request['password']),    i used like this way also failed

Comment: also you need to change ``Auth::attempt($request->only($credentials)`` to ``Auth::attempt($credentials)`` !!

Comment: kindly  learn first before copying pasting from other sources without understanding how basic stuffs works :)

Comment: also, you don;'t need to encrypt the password unless you're doing something else !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
public function check(Request $request){ 

    $credentials = $request->validate([
        'email'     => ['required', 'email'],
        'password'  => ['required'],
    ]);

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        echo "Sucess";
    }

    echo "fail";

}
```

Comment: i tried login fails

Comment: Please make sure your Auth namespace call or not

Comment: use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;    here i called

Comment: you need to controller header section with call namespace like: use Auth;

Comment: use Auth; i used still login fail

Comment: can u share your failed message here..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251588/discussion-between-abi-jega-and-md-delowar-hossen).